# No lights in Cycles viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

Hi I'm a beginner in  blender. I've modeled this house but when I switch to cycles viewport I can not see any light instead just grey color. I can clearly see the lights when I render the scene in cycles but not in viewport. even in eevee I have no problem with lights. its well lit up. but in cycles everything remains dark even when I've put a huge area light on top

[image: cycle viewport]

[image: eevee viewport]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the top left corner, the render is paused:

[image]

Click the pause button in the top right corner to resume rendering:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot its working now

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to upvote and mark my post as the answer.